# How to destroy dojo ListItem

Tags: javascript, templates, dojo, widget, destroy

Every time I enter a `dojox/mobile/View` I need to reload a `dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList`:

**javascript**

```
var list = registry.byId("myList");
var store = new Memory({data: JSON.parse(myData), idProperty: "label"});
list.setStore(store);
```

**html**

```
div(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollablePane")
    ul#myList(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList" data-dojo-props="itemRenderer: myItem, select: 'single'")
```

**list item**

```
define([
    "dojox/mobile/ListItem",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojox/mobile/Badge",
    "dojo/_base/declare"
], function (ListItem, TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Badge, declare) {
    var template =
        "<div class='areaDone${done}'>" +
        "       <div class='listDiv' style='display: inline;' data-dojo-attach-point='labelNode'></div>" +
        "       <div class='badgeDevices mblDomButtonBlueBadge' data-dojo-type='dojox/mobile/Badge' data-dojo-props='value:${devicesSize}'></div>" +
        "       <div class='badgeNotes' data-dojo-type='dojox/mobile/Badge' data-dojo-props='value:${notesSize}'></div>" +
        "</div>";

    TemplatedListItem = declare("myItem",
        [ListItem, TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
            label: "",
            notesSize: 0,
            devicesSize: 0,
            done: "false",
            templateString: template
        }
    );
});
```

when entering the views the second time I get the well-known error:

> Error: Tried to register widget with id==xxx but that id is already registered”

pointing at the `list.setStore()` line.
From documentation:

https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList

I don't understand which "destroy" function I need to call in order to empty the list from all (templated) widgets, and to be ready to fill it again.

Comment: list.destroyRecursive()

Comment: as far as I understand and after a test, it removes the widget completely. Instead I just need to clear the list to set again the store. No need to remove and create a new one.